# How do I make add the input parts into the loop like the menu?

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop, nested-loops

The part of the code that ask for the length of the list and then the actual numbers the users want to use needs to be looped into the program like the menu is looped in. So that once it runs and the program is fulfilled it can loop again. However, the program needs to completely end once the number -1000 is entered or option C from the menu is entered. When I try I keep getting errors. Can someone help, please?

I tried to move that statement into the loop, I tried to call it in the while loop, but when I do that it either prints the statement twice or just gives an error.

```
numbersEntered = []

def menu():
    print("[A] Smallest")
    print("[B] Largest")
    print("[C] Quit Game")

lengthNumbers = int(input("Please enter the length of your list/array:"))
print("Please enter your numbers individually:")


for x in range(lengthNumbers):
    data = int(input())
    numbersEntered.append(data) 
    if data == -1000:
        break

while numbersEntered[-1] != -1000:
    menu()
    Options=str(input(f"Please select either option A,B,or C:")).upper()
       
    if Options == 'A':
        print("The smallest number is:", min(numbersEntered))
    elif Options == 'B':
        print("The largest number is:", max(numbersEntered) )
        # check for 'C' input from user to break out of the while loop
    elif Options == 'C':
         break
print('Quit Game')
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. The code should be a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add the above items.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see you edited the code. Nice job. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

See comments in line.

```
import sys  # will be used to exit the game.

numbersEntered = []  # Accumulate the numbers provided by the user


# Since I see you are familiar with functions, use a function to end

def quit_game():
    print('Quit Game')
    sys.exit()


def menu():
    print("[A] Smallest")
    print("[B] Largest")
    print("[C] Quit Game")

# Get the starting number of number to process.
lengthNumbers = int(input("Please enter the length of your list/array:"))
print("Please enter your numbers individually:")

while True:
    for x in range(lengthNumbers):
        data = int(input())
        numbersEntered.append(data)
        if data == -1000:
            quit_game()
    # Once all numbers are entered provide the user a choice:
    # display the smallest or largest of the numbers or exit.
    menu()
    Options = str(input(f"Please select either option A,B,or C:")).upper()
    if Options == 'A':
        print("The smallest number is:", min(numbersEntered))
    elif Options == 'B':
        print("The largest number is:", max(numbersEntered))
        # check for 'C' input from user to break out of the while loop
    elif Options == 'C':
        quit_game()
    # Allow the user to process another set.
    lengthNumbers = int(input("Please enter the length of your list/array:"))
    print("Please enter your numbers individually:")
# print('Quit Game') Moved to the function
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but, when -1000 or C is pressed the code ends and an error pops up. Plus this doesn't address my main concern which is how do I make the whole thing a loop until -1000 or C are entered. That is my main problem.

Comment: @AbiExpoi, I revised the answer. Hope it is the solution you were looking for.